# how to sort a dictionary by key first then by tuple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Given an input dictionary like

```
{13: (3,1,7), 2: (6,4,9), 7: (5,8,4)}
```

get an out put dictionary like

```
{2: (4,6,9), 7: (4,5,8), 13: (1,3,7)}
```

Comment: A dictionary (atleast till the recent versions of Python) is not sorted. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

From Python 3.6 onwards, dictionaries honor insertion order. You can accomplish what you want by using `sorted` at the level of both the dict items as well as within the individual values:

```
>>> dict(sorted((k, tuple(sorted(v))) for (k, v) in a.items()))
{2: (4, 6, 9), 7: (4, 5, 8), 13: (1, 3, 7)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension.

```
a = {13: (3,1,7), 2: (6,4,9), 7: (5,8,4)}
sorted_a = {key:tuple(sorted(a[key])) for key in sorted(a)}
```